# PHP/AJAX checking users last online

Tags: php, ajax

I want to create a piece of code that checks if an individual user is online.

I have a nice style that can display a green online circle for if the user is online.

[Picture of PHP example](https://gyazo.com/0e49bdc9d2b640b451cd157d29d9d744)

I have the code to make this function for PHP but i want to make it available in real time (without the page refreshing, change the users icon to a grey circle for when they're offline or a green circle for when they're online) maybe using AJAX. Like I said, i have the classes to show the circles so I dont need any styling done. Just the AJAX to make it check if they're online without a refresh.

I also have a piece of code that checks how many clients are online without a refresh and is working but i'm not sure how to go about making that in to getting individual clients times. I will post both of my codes below.

My PHP working but without AJAX code (requires page load for user status to change) :

```
<?php
    $user_grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");
    while($users_ = mysqli_fetch_array($user_grab)) {



        $last_online = strtotime($users_['lastonline']);

        if(time() - $last_online < user_session_timeout()) {
            echo '
                 <div class="chat-list-item -available" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);">
                    <img class="chat-list-avatar" src="'.$users_['profile_picture'].'"/><i class="fa fa-circle chat-list-status"> </i>
                    <div class="chat-list-user">'.$users_['username'].' (<font size="2">'.get_users_level_all($users_['userLevel']).'</font>)</div>
                    <div class="chat-list-excerpt">Online</div>
                 </div>
            ';
        } else {
            echo '
                 <div class="chat-list-item -offline" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); padding: 5px;">
                    <img class="chat-list-avatar" src="'.$users_['profile_picture'].'"/><i class="fa fa-circle chat-list-status"> </i>
                    <div class="chat-list-user">'.$users_['username'].' (<font size="2">'.get_users_level_all($users_['userLevel']).'</font>)</div>
                    <div class="chat-list-excerpt">Offline</div>
                 </div>
            ';
        }   
    }
?>
```

`

I have some PHP code which works (it gets the current online users) but i dont know how to make it check each users online status and display different classes if they're online or offline.

The code :

```
$session    = session_id();
$time       = time();
$time_check = $time - 300;     //We Have Set Time 5 Minutes


$sql    = "SELECT * FROM online_users WHERE session = '$session'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$count  = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

//If count is 0 , then enter the values
if($count == "0") {
    $sql1    = "INSERT INTO online_users(session, time) VALUES ('$session', '$time')"; 
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
}

 // else update the values 
 else {
    $sql2    = "UPDATE online_users SET time = '$time' WHERE session = '$session'"; 
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2); 
}

 $sql3              = "SELECT * FROM online_users";
 $result3           = mysqli_query($con, $sql3); 
 $count_user_online = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
 echo "<b>Users Online : </b> $count_user_online "; 

 // after 5 minutes, session will be deleted 
 $sql4    = "DELETE FROM online_users WHERE time < $time_check"; 
 $result4 = mysqli_query($con, $sql4);
```

I only have AJAX for getting the online users for now.
I want a piece of AJAX code which will check each user's online status and display the different online / offline classes I use at the top section code of this question:

My AJAX for getting online clients :

```
<script>
    function fetchOnline() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/get_dash_settings.php",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(value){
                var data = value.split(",");
                $('#totalUsers').html(data[0]);
                $('#totalOnline').html(data[1]);
                $('#freeModeStatus').html(data[2]);
                $('#bypassesStatus').html(data[3]);
            },
            complete:function(){
               setTimeout(fetchOnline,5000);
            }
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function() { setInterval(fetchOnline,5000); });
</script>
```

Comment: well, how would you know if they are online? Usually, websites just guess based on time since a connection.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey The second code I posted works perfectly. It updates, inserts and deletes fields in my table called online_clients. I just need to some how make it read each clients online status individually.

Comment: Could you post the AJAX code you're trying to use?

Comment: I'd suggest to return a json with all the users (online or offline) from `get_dash_settings.php` and update the html in js in succes callback rather than getting and updating full html.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that rather than return JSON with information about that user along with another JSON keypair about how many users are on line. Then, you can act on the JSON that is returned to update elements on your page based on the results.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide me with an example.

Comment: Well, to start with, in your ajax section, you need to add dataType: "JSON" so that it knows to expect JSON in the return value. And there are plenty of tutorials on how to treat JSON data in javascript. 

On the php side, create an array of the information you want to return and then echo that back with json_encode(). So if you have an array name $array, do this: echo json_encode($array);
Then JSON will be returned back to your jQuery success variable

Comment: @Difter Why would I use an array to check for each user's online time ?

Comment: I was under the impression you want to show which users were on line at a given time. You'd store those in an array and ship that back to your AJAX success as JSON and then iterate through it to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what db engine you are using. I'm going to assume MySql, where you can do joins.

In that case, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN online_users ON users.id=online_users.id
```

However, I cannot tell what your schema is and how you would connect an online_user to a user. You either have a sessions table in-between that you could use, or you will need to store the id or username of the user in the online_users table. Right now, you only have session and time, and I'm not sure how to connect a session to a user.

You could then tell if the user is online using:

```
!is_null($users_['time'])
```